# If $U,H$ are Hilbert spaces, then $X:\Omega\to\mathfrak L(U,H)$ is measurable iff $\langle X,h\rangle_H$ is measurable for all $h\in H$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space
- $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space
- $\mathcal B(E)$ denote the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $$
- $X:\Omega\to E$

Remember that

- $X$ is called $\mathcal A$-measurable $:\Leftrightarrow$ $$X^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal A\;\;\;\text{for all }B\in\mathcal B(E)\tag0\;.$$
- $X$ is called strongly $\mathcal A$-measurable $:\Leftrightarrow$ $X$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable and $X(\Omega)$ is separable
- $X$ is called weakly $\mathcal A$-measurable $:\Leftrightarrow$ $$\varphi(X)\text{ is }\mathcal A\text{-measurable}\;\;\;\text{for all }\varphi\in E'\tag1$$

Now, assume that $E=\mathfrak L(U,H)$ for some $\mathbb R$-Hilbert spaces $U,H$. $X$ is called *simply $\mathcal A$-measurable* $:\Leftrightarrow$ $$Xu\text{ is strongly }\mathcal A\text{-measurable}\;\;\;\text{for all }u\in U\tag2\;$$

> I want to show that $X$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable $\Leftrightarrow$ $$\langle X,h\rangle_H\text{ is }\mathcal A\text{-measurable}\;\;\;\text{for all }h\in H\;;\tag3$$ at least if $U$ (and maybe $H$) is separable.

First of all, since $U$ is reflexive, we obtain the separability of $U'$ from the separability of $U$. Hence, by $(3)$, $$\langle X,h\rangle_H\text{ is strongly }\mathcal A\text{-measurable}\;\;\;\text{for all }h\in H\;.\tag4$$

> However, I don't know how I need to proceed from here. Maybe we're are only able to show the equivalence to the simple $\mathcal A$-measurability of $X$ ...

Comment: I'm confused.  What does "$\mathcal{A}$-measurable" mean?  You defined "strongly $\mathcal{A}$-measurable," "weakly $\mathcal{A}$-measurable," and "simply $\mathcal{A}$-measurable," but not "$\mathcal{A}$-measurable."

Comment: @fourierwho By $\mathcal A$-measurable I mean the "usual" notion of measurability, i.e.: $X$ is called $\mathcal A$-measurable (more precisely, $(\mathcal A,\mathcal B(E))$-measurable), iff $$X^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal A\;\;\;\text{for all }B\in\mathcal B(E)\tag0\;.$$ I've added the definition to the question.